# How To Only Show a $ In a Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I only want a $ to show up in my terminal (mac) instead of: Macintosh:~ username$

I tried to change it in the settings but that didn't work...
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try installing 'oh my zsh'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit `~/.bash_profile`

add the following line: `export PS1="$ "`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by editing `~/.bash_profile`

There are lots of tutorials online.